How to save time when the app is closed in flutter?
I want a save or store time in shared_preferences when the app is closed. and after opining the app; I need the stored or saved time for reaming time the calculate the timer when the app was closed.

Okay... so what of this can you do, and what do you need help with?

I want a timer to decreasing become time from current time. i.e. this is my beginning time '05:23:23' and if the the current time or DateTime.now() is going up my time should goes to come down, and if I am going to close the app for 05min and 13sec, and opening the app' timer should not start from the beginning '05:23:23' the up should start from the passed times '05:18:10'. Now I want to save the time when app is closed and when app is start I want the time should decrease passed and when the app closed. I hope you got what I need.

I got what you need, but we are not a code writing service. What of the above is something you already can do, and what specifically do you need help with? Can you get the time? Can you count it down? Can you write to shared_preferences? Can you read from shared_preferences?

for this purpose listen app state, extend your class with a mixin WidgetsBindingObserver and override the didChangeAppLifecycleState method
example code
class _FooState extends State<Foo> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
     /// write you code here
    }
  }
}


In AppLifecycleState.paused if we are using this method everything we want it can stop. But I need when the time is going and the app is stoped my time  '05:23:23' also should go. And if I opened the app the my time should not be in there  '05:23:23' I need to count how many time the app was not used; the app also subtract paused or stopped or not used app time in my time. I hope you got the point Mr. Khuram Shabbir. And thank you for your guides.
